# itunes connect in-app purchase test user account is temporarily unavailable

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

My in-app purchase was working fine till Wednesday. But yesterday onwards when am clicking on "Buy" button, after some seconds am getting following message . "Your account is temporarily unavailable.Please try again later".I am using itunesconncet test user account for testing.Is this a itunesconncet sandbox error  or my problem ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps it really is *temporarily* unavailable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am also having the same problem.  In app purchasing in the sandbox was working flawlessly on 12/06 and 12/07.  I noticed starting on 12/08 (yesterday) and 12/09 (today) that the sandbox basically doesn't work.

I'll get the "Your account is temporarily unavailable..." just about every time.  Every now and then upon restarting my app, I'll get the "you've already paid for this purchase..." message.

Sounds like I'm not the only one.  I tried restoring my iPhone as I've heard this may work.  It did not.

***update 12/11/2010***

I've contacted Apple twice.  Both times, I used the email address suggested by the itunes connect "contact us" algorithm.  They responded the first time with:

*...we provide support for code-level questions on hardware & software development, and are unable to help you with your question.  For questions regarding iTunes Connect issues, please direct your inquiry through the iTunes Connect Contact Us system:  www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus

Confused, I just sent them another email saying:

*I wrote an inquiry several days ago regarding problems with the in app purchase sandbox.  Basically, the sandbox has not been working correctly for 3 days now.  Please see:  [itunes connect in-app purchase test user account is temporarily unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406440/itunes-connect-in-app-purchase-test-user-account-is-temporarily-unavailable)
I don't know what to do.  The link that was provided by [above] is the same link that tells me to send an email to Apple Technical Support Developer.  However, according to [you] this isn't correct.  But the itunesconnect "contact us" worksheet, takes me to this (see screenshot attached).
I would love to not go 'round and 'round a corporate maze until this gets into the right hands.  Please look into your in app purchase sandbox.  It is not working and has delayed the release of my update probably until after the holidays.  Losing the last 3 days of testing has been devastating to my chances of releasing an update before the holiday itunesconnect shut down on 12/23.  Considering the 7+ day review process I needed to submit my update by the end of this weekend.*

I'll post back when I get a response.

**update 12/13**

nothing from apple, yet.  but, we're not alone:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/55055?tstart=0

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/64459?tstart=0

Comment: update 12/14: Apple has confirmed to me they know this is a problem and it is in their bug tracker. Don't know when it's going to be resolved. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating another Test Account to see if that error still occurs. If not, then get rid of the old test account and continue to use the new one.